# Write generator function for LSTM text generation model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

i have a LSTM model for text generation but when trying to increase the amount of data to input, I run into RAM issues so I found out that I can use fit_generator function to load the data in step by step.

The problem is currently that **keras.utils.to_categorical** takes to much space when the amount of unique words increases.

So i want to convert this code block into a generator function:

```
x_values, labels = input_seqs[:, :-1], input_seqs[:, -1]
y_values = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes=total_unique_words)

#Shape of x_values: (152250, 261)
#Shape of y_values: (152250, 4399)
```

And i got something like this but I'm not sure how to assign the right values to *batch_x* and *batch_y*

```
def generator(input_seq, batch_size):

    index = 0 
    while True:
      batch_x = np.zeros((batch_size, max_seq_length-1))
      batch_y = np.zeros((batch_size, total_unique_words))
      for i in range(batch_size):
        batch_x[i] = input_seqs[:, :-1][i]
        batch_y[i] = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(input_seqs[:, -1][i], num_classes=total_unique_words)
        index = index + 1
        if index == len(input_seq):
          index = 0

      yield batch_x, batch_y
```

Full code for better overview:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(review_list)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
total_unique_words = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1 

input_sequences = []
for line in review_list:
  token_list = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([line])[0]
  for i in range(1, len(token_list)):
    n_gram_seqs = token_list[:i+1]
    input_sequences.append(n_gram_seqs)

max_seq_length = max([len(x) for x in input_sequences])
input_seqs = np.array(pad_sequences(input_sequences, maxlen=max_seq_length, padding='pre'))

x_values, labels = input_seqs[:, :-1], input_seqs[:, -1]
y_values = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes=total_unique_words)

callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=3)
K.clear_session()
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim = total_unique_words, output_dim=100, input_length=max_seq_length-1),
tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256, return_sequences=True), 
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2), 
tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256), 
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(total_unique_words , activation='softmax')])
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
def generator(input_seq, batch_size, dataset_size):

    no_batches = int(dataset_size/batch_size)
    batch_x = np.zeros((batch_size, max_seq_length-1))
    batch_y = np.zeros((batch_size, total_unique_words))

    for i in range(no_batches):
        batch_x = input_seqs[:, :-1][(i*batch_size) : ((i+1)*batch_size)]
        batch_y = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(input_seqs[:, -1][(i*batch_size) : ((i+1)*batch_size)], num_classes=total_unique_words)

        yield batch_x, batch_y

    return
```

I added the `dataset_size`(152250 in your case) argument so that the number of batches could be calculated.

Comment: Thank you, this does seem to work. But it does increase the training time substantially, is that expected behaviour? If so do you maybe know something to speed it up?

Comment: Yes, it is expected behavior. You can speed it up by creating a custom data generator with `tf.keras`, as opposed to your own. To do so, you create a new data generator class by subclassing `tf.keras.utils.Sequence` and implement the `__get_item__()` and `__len__()` dunder methods. The first one returns a batch of data, and the second, the size of your dataset. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence) is a link to the docs. This is faster because it uses multi-processing to load the next batch of data while your model trains.